# Illustrator - "real" inner shadow to SVG object

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

**Wanted: An inset shadow (NOT inner glow) for a complex svg path, supporting following options:**

- shadow/light direction
- shadow size
- blur amount
- opacity

[Example Pic: Inset Shadow for SVG-Paths (SVG Effect)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rIQy.png)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question. As such it would seem to fit better on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

select the svg object, open appearance toolbar, use this icon [image] at the bottom to add svg-filter

[image]

use "+" to add a new filter and copy following code

```
<filter  id="inset-shadow">
    <feOffset  dx="25" dy="25"></feOffset>
    <feGaussianBlur  result="offset-blur" stdDeviation="10"></feGaussianBlur>
    <feComposite  in="SourceGraphic" in2="offset-blur" operator="out" result="inverse"></feComposite>
    <feFlood  flood-color="black" flood-opacity=".75" result="color"></feFlood>
    <feComposite  in="color" in2="inverse" operator="in" result="shadow"></feComposite>
    <feComposite  in="shadow" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="over"></feComposite>
</filter>
```

- dx="25" dy="25": shadow width
- stdDeviation="10": blur width
- flood-opacity=".75": opacity